# Cannot read nodes containing an email address

Tags: database

```
    $email = "example@addresss.com";

    if (valid_email_address($email)) {
      $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
      $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'my_content_type')
        //->fieldCondition('field_user_email_address', "email", $email)
        ->propertyCondition('status', 1);

      $result = $query->execute();
      dpm($result,"result");
      if (!empty($result['node'])) {
        $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
        $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
          dpm($node,$node->title);
        }
      }
    }
```

The problem I have is with the fieldCondition (commented out above).  When it's commented out, the $result returns all of the matching nodes, as expected.  Looking at the second dpm output I can see results for "example@addresss.com" in $var->field_user_email_address[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['email'] = "example@addresss.com".

However, when the fieldCondition is included in the search, it always returns zero results.   i.e. $result is an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're having trouble with the bundle condition, but as an alternative you could use a `propertyCondition` and query on the node type instead:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('type', 'my_content_type')
  ->fieldCondition('field_user_email_address', "email", $email)
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
```